# How to modify/add post parameters in symfony?

Tags: symfony1

How do I add more parameters to sfRequest object, on server side, before the request is processed?

I tried below code but it does not work.

```
$request->setParameter('formname[id]');
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: For what purpose do you want to do this? setParameter has two mandatory arguments.

Comment: I wanted to pull an item from encrypted cookie and make it part of request.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Adding parameters to sfRequest object is quite simple.

```
$request->setParameter('newParam', 'newParamValue');
//see your added param
var_dump($request->getParameter('newParam'));
```

The problem i think you may have faced is, with array parameters
Supposed you want to add "id" to your parameter "formname".

```
$newParams = array('id'=>1);

//Merge the existing values in formname with your new value
$formnameArray = $request->getParameter('formname');
$mergedArray = array_merge($formnameArray, $newParams);

//save it back in the request obj
$request->setParameter('formname', $mergedArray);
```

This should do it.

Answer (score 2):

You can access the public `request` attribute from `$request` and set or add parameters.
Example:

```
$request->request->set("p1", "v1");
$request->request->set("p2", "v2");
```

Or

```
$request->request->add(array("p1"=>"v1", "p2"=>"v2"));
```

Answer (score 1):

The above solution is not firendly to implement with multi-level array (with i18n for exemple).

```
//get the array
$formnameArray = $request->getParameter('formname');
//alter the array
$formnameArray['id'] = $newID;
$request->setParameter('formname', $formnameArray);
```

No need to merge your brain.